# Naming of related classes and interfaces

Tags: c#, .net, naming, coding-standards

I have created an `ObjectParser` class which parses data into strongly typed objects using an `IObjectParserDataSource` as the data source (the data could be an Excel file, text file, array, query string, etc).

Examples of my implementations of `IObjectParserDataSource` are:

- `TextFileObjectParserDataSource`
- `ExcelFileObjectParserDataSource`

These class names feel really long and convoluted to me.

I could name them:

- `TextFileDataSource`
- `ExcelFileDataSource`

But this introduces a level of ambiguity and they don't became as clearly related to `IObjectParserDataSource` at first glance.  This becomes important because defining these data sources will happen in client code and I wish to minimize potential confusion and uncertainty.

**How would you name these classes in such a scenario?**

Comment: I don't think your current names are too long and convoluted.

Comment: I'm throwing this idea out there, but I don't recommend it: If you use the same string (such as "ObjectParserDataSource") a lot in your naming, acronym it.  `ExcelFileOPDS`, `TextFileOPDS`.  It saves a bit on typing and screen space, but it's opaque to someone who isn't familiar with the code.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I generally try to get around this problem by sticking all similar objects into one namespace and simplifying their names (if I can do it).

For example, would have

```
namespace ObjectParserDataSources
|
|-> class TextFileSource
|-> class ExcelFileSource
```

Or, if the collection of objects working with/servicing `ObjectParser` becomes large enough, I'd make a separate folder tree or project devoted just to ObjectParser:

```
namespace ObjectParser
|
|-> class ObjectParser
|-> interface IObjectParserDataSource
|
|-> namespace DataSources
|   |
|   |-> class TextFileSource
|   |-> class ExcelFileSource
|
|-> other stuff...
```

Within any given file, the import statements and the code context would usually make it pretty clear that `TextFileSource` is the `ObjectParser` data source.  If there are multiple similarly named classes in the same piece of code, you can refer to `TextFileSource` by its full name:

```
var parserSource = new ObjectParser.DataSources.TextFileSource(/*...*/);
```

It usually occurs very rarely and I don't mind typing out extra few words.

Comment: You saved me the time of typing out that same answer :)

Comment: +1. This solution improves readability without reducing clarity.